# How to get all specific elements of list of a custom class

Tags: java, list

I have a list of elements of a custom class as defined here:

```
private List<CoreVersionDetails> children;
```

CoreVersionDetails.java :

```
public class CoreVersionDetails {
private String uri;
private boolean folder;

public String getUri() {
    return uri;
}

public void setUri(String input) {
    this.uri = input;
}

public boolean getFolder() {
    return folder;
}

public void setFolder(boolean input) {
    this.folder = input;
}}
```

Now , I can suppose get one element of the list "children" of category uri by using:

```
 children.get(0).geturi();
```

How do I get all the elements of children.geturi ?

Comment: `children.stream().map(CoreVersionDetails::getUri).collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: This question is not clear..  What is the expected output here.. getUri returns a string and they all have a URI, what does he mean by get all elements of getUri ?